# Getting user's facebook id with the link to their profile

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, facebook-graph-api, ejs

I'm developing a website where each user can provide a link to their facebook profile using express and basic ejs. I'm trying to figure out a way to display the user's facebook profile picture as their profile picture on my website through a tag using `ejs` like `<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<%= user.fb_id %>/picture?type=large">`

But since the profile link doesn't give the user's facebook id directly, I was wondering how I could go about this using `node`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the (App Scoped) ID of a user, and/or his profile picture, is by authorizing that user with your App. For data privacy reasons, it is not possible to get any data of a user with his profile URL only. You can then use the App Scoped ID for the `/picture` endpoint.